# Dynamic routing using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to have my application route to different pages of the website based on the id of an item that is in json file.

I have
`<Route path="products/:id" elemet={<ProductDetails />}/>` in the parent component which is supposed to route to

```
import useFetch from "./useFetch"
export default function ProductDetails(){
    // program doesn't even get here
    const {id} = useParams()
    const {data: product, error, isPending} = useFetch("http://localhost:8000/products/" + id)
    console.log(product) //this doesn't even print
    
    return(
        <div className="product-details">
            {console.log("hello")}
            {/* not linking properly, below doesnt show */}
            <h1>product</h1>
            {isPending && <div>Loading...</div> }
            {error && <div>{error}</div> }
            {product && (
                <article>
                    <h2>{product.title}</h2>
                    <p>{product.overview}</p>
                </article>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The link that is related to the redirect is the below

```
export default function ProductList({products,title}){
    return(
        <div className="product-list">
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {/* this doesn't show */}
            <h1>{products.overview}</h1>
            {/* below doesn not work(?) */}
            {products.map((product) =>
                <div className="product-preview" key={product.id}>
                    {console.log("inside the mapping function: " + product)}

                    {/* link displays an empty page .. not sure why */}
                    {/* No routes matched location "/product/0" - error message */}
                    <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`}>
                        <h2>{product.title}</h2>
                        <p>{product.overview}</p>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The main error I am getting when I go into the console is
`Matched leaf route at location "/products/0" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.`

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong, I know that my `useFetch()` custom hook is working as it 'shows' three components (I only have 3 in the json file), you can tell they're there by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj3Tt.png) (I used CSS to add a border around each item)

I am new-ish to react, and am learning how to use react routing to develop my skills. Any help would be greatly apprecaited!

Comment: I don't see any `<Route>` tag in your code

Comment: it is at the top of my post, instead of putting app.jsx entirely i just put the relevant line.

Answer (score 0):

What about the parent route, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

`<Route path="products/:id" elemet={<ProductDetails />}/>` had a typo,
should be `<Route path="products/:id" element={<ProductDetails />}/>`. Element was spelled wrong.